# Java Consumer Interface pass value

Tags: java, java-8

Im trying to use Java Consumer Interface to get rid of redundant code.
I have an object like this:

```
public class Data {
    private int id;
    private String d1;
    private String d2;
    private String d3;
    private String d4;
}

@Getter
public class Container {
    private List<Data> data;
}
```

An several functions that change the values of the data object like this:

```
public static void actionForD1(Container container) {
    container.getData().forEach(data -> {
        Source s = getSource(data.getId());
        String value = s.getValueForD1();
        //do maybe some more transformation with the value
        data.setD1(value);
    });
}

public static void actionForD2(Container container) {
    container.getData().forEach(data -> {
        Source s = getSource(data.getId());
        String value = s.getValueForD2();
        //do maybe some more transformation with the value
        data.setD2(value);
    });
}
...
```

They all have the same routine. Iterate over the Data objects, get the Source object and based on the id and do some calculations.

Now is it possible to use the Java Consumer Interface to do something like this

```
 process(container,  data -> {
    String value = s.getSomething();
    //do maybe some more stuff with value 
    data.setD2(value);
});

public static void process(Container container, Consumer<Data> c) {
    container.getData().forEach(data -> {
        Source s = getSource(data.getId());
        c(s);
    });
}
```

The problem with my approach is, that the Source object is not accessible inside the consumer. Is there possibility to do it? Or is this a bad approach?

Comment: Your `actionForD2` doesn't make any sense. It references `container` when there's no such parameter

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking for something like this:

```
public void takeAction(Container container, BiConsumer<Data, Source> op) {
    container.getData().forEach(data -> {
        Source s = getSource(data.getId());
        op.accept(data, s);
    });
}

BiConsumer<Data, Source> actionforD1 = (Data d, Source s) -> {
    String v = s.getValueForD1();
    // do maybe some more transformation with the value
    d.setD1(v);
};

BiConsumer<Data, Source> actionforD2 = (Data d, Source s) -> {
    String v = s.getValueForD2();
    // do maybe some more transformation with the value
    d.setD2(v);
};

public void businessLogic(Container c) {
    takeAction(c, actionforD1);
    takeAction(c, actionforD2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two functional interfaces to provide an `id` which is a parameter of the `Source` look-up and the actual setter for `Data` to be performed.

```
public static void action(
    Container container, Function<Data, Integer> idFunction, BiConsumer<Data, String> setter) 
{
    container.getData().forEach(data -> {
        Source s = getSource(idFunction.apply(data));
        String value = s.getSomething();
        setter.accept(data, value);
    });
}
```

The usage is fairly flexible:

```
action(new Container(), Data::getId, Data::setD1);  // Source from data.id

Data externalData = ...
int id = externalData.getId();
action(new Container(), data -> id , Data::setD2);  // Source from external id
```

Also note that in your implementation of `actionForD2` method, the parameter `data` cannot be used in the lambda expression as long as it's already defined at the method parameters level.

Comment: +1.  Really?  It seems to me that `data.getId()` is static, so first function not needed.  Then, it seems to me that `s.getSomething()` is one of the things that is variable.  That's what the OPs example seems to show.  But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I see the `s.getSomething()` is same, but `Source s` is variable and dependant on `data.getId()`. Moreover, I see two cases - one the id is obtained from the `Data` originating *in lambda* and the second one the `Data` is passed from *the method* and the one in lambda is ignored for getting the ID.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Thanks for you answer. I updated my Question to make it a bit more clearer. 
So each action does not use the same function to receive the value, and after receiving the value, each action may do process the value differently

Comment: Could you specify examples of what could appear instead of `// do maybe some more transformation with the value`?

Comment: I'd like to hear a reason of the donvote in order to improve my answer. Thanks.